# How to find a specific NES pirate, unlicensed or bootleg game information?

Tags: nes

As a kid, I've played a lot of NES. In my country, unlicensed games and famiclones were pretty frequent (boosted by the market reserve strategy to produce every component in-house), and games with generic names like [Puzzle](http://nesguide.com/games/puzzle/) or [F-15 Civil War](http://nesguide.com/games/f-15-city-war/) got distributed [bundled with those clones](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qkYTUEklgd8/Vj0lZVMaj9I/AAAAAAAACRk/f5f0Pgcs9_Y/s1600/Dynavision-Novo-Mesmo-2-cartuchos-20131103173657.jpg), and cartidges had labels like "Puzzle Game" or "JET game". However, there is this "*Tank*" unregistered game, that is neither [Iron Tank](http://nesguide.com/games/iron-tank-the-invasion-of-normandy/) nor [Battle City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_City_(video_game)) and uses some sprites of both. The same word is printed on the cartidge label(that is minimalistic and with no artwork - below) and shows at the opening screen.

The gameplay was pretty simple:

- 1 or 2 player(white and green tanks);
- Defeat all tanks and stationary cannons through stages to achieve next stages;
- About 50 levels with different level shapes;
- Different kinds of enemy tanks(fast ones, all direction shot ones, upgrade ones);

[image: default bundle cartidges on many of the famiclones]

How can I find a game that is probably a bootleg and has such generic name that composes part of names of other registered NES games?  Searching for "unlicensed" "tank" "pirate" "bootleg" show no relevant results, or results that are only related to other licensed games, and it's modifications.

**See more:**

- [Piracy Is a Part of Video Game History in Brazil](https://iq.intel.com/en-in/video-game-piracy-is-a-part-of-history-in-brazil-3/)
- [Brazil's Video Game Gray market](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MU29Wqg_BVo). Documentary about how bootlegs spread in Brazil and how some videogames manufactured inside the contry were legal, and some illegal.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question here?  You found it.  That's great.  But...that's not a question.  We generally don't reopen game identification questions once you figure out what they are, because there's no longer a question.

Comment: To add stuff that is interesting to other find bootlegs like the "Other stuff" section of my answer. Could help others on their search. The other question was closed by totally different reasons. You seem to miss all the point at my answer, on helping others to identify their missing bootleg games.

Comment: The point is, a question has to stand on it's own, without an answer.  As it stands, what you're asking is really hard to understand.  If you're asking how to find this one specific game, that's generally a shopping rec, and off-topic.  If you're detailing how you found this game, that's still not a *question*.  What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Alright, I can see you tried to follow my suggestions from our discussion, which is great. :) However, the bulk of the question reads as an ITG sort of question, which although you retroactively added the needed artifact, doesn't really work here (which I warned you would be the case). If you strip out the why you did this (or strip it down), this could likely be a viable post.

Comment: I'm with Frank on this one. We only do game identification question on this site if you provide an artifact from the game - typically a screenshot. The image you gave literally has the game name right there, along with the company that produced it. So there's not really a question other than "tell me about this game", which is too broad IMO.

Comment: IF you make this less specifically about the Tank game and more about how to find info about unlicensed games, this stands a better shot of not being close voted and disappearing. Your goals are laudable, I get you want to share the info you found during your search, just the approach could use work.

Comment: Just give me some time to work on a more "generic" approach of finding those kind of games info

Comment: OK. All Tank related stuff removed from the question itself. I hope this time i've lost searching for this game should help others :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** My first(closed) question about this subject was closed in May 2015 and there was none of the information below on the internet, meaning that maybe you will have to persevere and also give some time between your searches.

The main method I've used to find this game was, of course, affected by an immense luck: reading NES news and waiting for information about this unlicensed game to reach the internet. Searching for "unlicensed", "pirate" and "tank" got me nowhere in my hunt for this game. I would be happy by just finding some of the game screens and its music you know, to feel the nostalgia even if I didn't find the ROM.

I had almost given up on searching this game, but this "new wave" of unreleased Nintendo stuff we are facing today([Playstation Snes](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2015/07/fabled-sony-nintendo-play-station-prototype-discovered/), [Star Fox 2](http://web.archive.org/web/20180101223636/https://www.nintendo.com/super-nes-classic/interview-star-fox-2), [Sim City for Nes](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2017/09/not_one_but_two_prototypes_for_nes_sim_city_are_discovered)) uncovered a [Caltron 9 in 1](https://www.gamingconviction.com/caltron-9-in-1-nes-prototype-surfaces/) cartridge with unlicensed games that were never released, and it was on auction [on Ebay](https://web.archive.org/web/20151121024449/http://www.ebay.com/itm/CALTRON-9-IN-1-PROTOTYPE-6-IN-1-TEST-RARE-NINTENDO-GAMES-NES-CARTS-NOT-MYRIAD-/262147355141).

As soon as I looked at the home screen and got the "Tank" at the list of games, I've searched for "Tank Caltron" on Google, that [sent me to this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8amdVa0cVQ&t=3s)(as you can see, I'm the only one that commented on that footage). The only indexed game with Caltron publisher [at NESGuide](http://nesguide.com/publishers/caltron/) was the old 6 in 1 cartridge (that doesn't have Tank).

This also led me to another research based on this company alias (Youtube video description) and I could find that [NTDEC](http://bootleggames.wikia.com/wiki/NTDEC) was the most popular alias to this company in Brazil, hence the "NTDEC" at the opening. Searching for "NTDEC", "unlicensed" and "lists" I could find:

- [This awesome updated list of unlicensed games](https://fcgamer.wordpress.com/2014/07/06/updated-game-lists/)(no download links, only a pretty complete info list);
- [NTDEC Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTDEC#List_of_titles_developed_as_NTDEC) linked a Spanish page called [Gluk video](http://www.kaiserland77.com/wikines77/index.php/Gluk:_Los_Juegos_del_Naranjito) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and searching for Tank, found more relevant stuff;
- *Found the ROM. HELL YEAH!!!!* Sorry guys, can't post this stuff here ;) But sure i'm still playing this game :)

**Things to pay attention for when searching for unlicensed games:**

- Game publishers have aliases. NTDEC for example, had 4 of them.
- Sometimes, unlicensed games are called "bootlegs" but they aren't a modified version of an existing game but a mesh-up of sprites and sounds from other games.
- Search for those "X in 1" cartridges that comes with clones(Famiclones in this case). They could be holding the game you are looking for, giving additional assets.

  - Also, try to search online for Famiclone bundles info if you owned one that has the cartridge you want. Mine unfortunately was a [Milmar Top System](https://games.mercadolivre.com.br/games/top-system-milmar)(brazilian online store) bundled with [F-15 Civil War](http://nesguide.com/games/f-15-city-war/) on its package. None of the other bundle options of Top System had "Tank". The game I was looking for was part of another clone bundle that I couldn't remember, which a friend of mine owned but he sold me the cartridge only.
- Keep tracking for words like "Nes Cartridge Ebay/auction/bid" at the news section of search engines.
- Use online image search if you know the cartidge uses some weird case like the one on the question(instead of those pretty common yellow nes 60-pin unlicensed cartidges, or de default gray 72-pin nes cartidge for example). Maybe you can find someone selling the game or a blogpost about it where you can ask things.
- Have the physical cartridge and put it to play (be carefull with old cartridges and old videogames being turned on). It may sound obvious but the cartridge I had with that game got lost during city change at my childhood, making this quest way more difficult.

**Other interesting sources I found during my hunt:**

- [BootlegGames wiki](http://bootleggames.wikia.com/wiki/NTDEC)
- [Lost games wiki](http://lost-games.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Nintendo_Entertainment_System_games)
- [FCPic(japanese)](http://fcpic.nesbbs.com/). This one is awesome cause it compares some games with its bootleg versions, for example, [Duck Hunt versions](http://fcpic.nesbbs.com/game_pic.asp?gameid=414).
- [FC Game Land](https://fcgamer.wordpress.com/). This guy has some passion about this kind of games.
- [cah4e3 cartbase](http://cah4e3.shedevr.org.ru/cartsbase.php). This other guy is doing an awesome job of indexing bootleg/pirated games and it's covers.